# catching created IDs in cursor loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following cursor (something like it anyways) that I am using to copy entries for a table that is part of a many to many relationship. I need the new IDs that are generated during the INSERT INTO B statement to update a junction table with.

```
DECLARE

BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (SELECT id
                 FROM A
                WHERE group_id = 7)
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO B (b_id, thing2, ...stuff...);

      INSERT INTO C (rec.id, /* new ID generated by previous insert statement */
      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

How do I capture the b_id value after the insert to use in the second INSERT statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [RETURNING clause](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm):

```
DECLARE

  v_bid B.b_id%TYPE;

BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (SELECT id
                 FROM A
                WHERE group_id = 7)
   LOOP
     INSERT INTO B (b_id, thing2, ...stuff...) RETURNING b_id INTO v_bid;

     INSERT INTO C (rec.id, /* new ID generated by previous insert statement */
     COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

That said, it's possible this operation could be performed without the use of a cursor.

Comment: Did know about the returning clause! Thanks. This is somewhat of a contrived example of what I am working on for which I believe I do need a cursor.

Comment: @Casey: Figured as much, just put it out there about the cursor.  IIRC, Oracle has supported the RETURNING clause since 9i.  PostgreSQL supports it, too.